# Trying to implement "the essence of the iterator pattern"

Tags: haskell, applicative

I came across the paper "https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf" which has code examples in quite an abstract pseudo haskell syntax.

I'm struggeling to implement the example from section 6.2. in real haskell.
This is how far I came:

```
module Iterator where
import Data.Functor.Const               -- for Const
import Data.Monoid (Sum (..), getSum)   -- for Sum
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy         -- for State
import Control.Applicative              -- for WrappedMonad


data Prod m n a = Prod {pfst:: m a, psnd:: n a} deriving (Show)

instance (Functor m, Functor n) => Functor (Prod m n) where    
fmap f (Prod m n) = Prod (fmap f m) (fmap f n)

instance (Applicative m, Applicative n) => Applicative (Prod m n) where
    pure x = Prod (pure x) (pure x)
    mf <*> mx = Prod (pfst mf <*> pfst mx) (psnd mf <*> psnd mx)

-- Functor Product
x :: (Functor m, Functor n) => (a -> m b) -> (a -> n b) -> (a -> Prod m n b)
(f `x` g) y = Prod (f y) (g y) 


type Count = Const (Sum Integer)
count :: a -> Count b
count _ = Const 1

cciBody :: Char -> Count a
cciBody = count

cci :: String -> Count [a]
cci = traverse cciBody

lciBody :: Char -> Count a
lciBody c = Const (Sum $ test (c == '\n'))

test :: Bool -> Integer
test b = if b then 1 else 0

lci :: String -> Count [a]
lci = traverse lciBody

clci :: String -> Prod Count Count [a]
clci = traverse (cciBody `x` lciBody)
-- up to here the code is working

-- can't get this to compile:
wciBody :: Char -> (WrappedMonad (Prod (State Bool) Count)) a
wciBody c =  pure $ state (updateState c) where
    updateState :: Char -> Bool -> (Integer, Bool)
    updateState c w = let s = c /= ' ' in (test (not(w && s)), s)

wci :: String -> (WrappedMonad (Prod (State Bool) Count)) [a]
wci = traverse wciBody

clwci :: String -> (Prod (Prod Count Count) (WrappedMonad (Prod (State Bool) Count))) [a]
clwci = traverse (cciBody `x` lciBody `x` wciBody)

str :: [Char]
str = "hello \n nice \t and \n busy world"

iteratorDemo = do
    print $ clci str
    print $ clwci str
```

The problematic spot is wciBody where I have no idea how to implement the ⇑ function from the paper.
Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't `Prod` need to be a monad for you to use it with `WrappedMonad`?

Comment: Isn't everything already an iterator in Haskell? For example `last [1 .. n]` will iterate over the list and not generate the entire list.

Comment: @Elmex80s I think you are confusing two different concepts, what Python would call an iterable and an iterator. Once contains values that can be iterated over; the other provides the interface for actually doing the iteration. For example, `x = list(range(100))` is an iterable, but `i1 = iter(x)` and `i2 = iter(x)` are two independent iterators. The number of times you call `next(i1)` does not affect the return value of the next call to `next(i2)`.

Comment: (It's a subtle distinction, as there are many examples in Python where you get an iterator for an iterable implicitly. `for i in x` first creates a new iterator for `x`, then uses that to iterate over the values in `x`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you may be mis-translating between the infix type operators used in the paper with the prefix type constructors in your definitions. I say this because the paper contains

```
wciBody :: Char → ( (State Bool) ⊡ Count) a
```

You have translated this as

```
wciBody :: Char -> (WrappedMonad (Prod (State Bool) Count)) a
```

which I don't think makes sense: `Prod x y` has no Monad instance, so it makes no sense to wrap it in WrapMonad. Rather, you are intended to read the ⊡ character as separating its entire left half ( `(State Bool)`) from its right half (`Count`), similar to how value-level operators in Haskell parse:

```
wciBody :: Char -> Prod (WrappedMonad (State Bool)) Count a
```

This makes more sense, doesn't it? Prod now takes three arguments, the first two of which are each of kind `* -> *`, and WrappedMonad's argument is clearly a monad. Does this change get you back on track?

Comment: Thanks a ton! You were right, I got confused about the precedence of . In addition I also confused the ⊡ (composition) operator with ⊠ (product)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the hint by amalloy I finally got the example code working.

Here is what I came up with:

```
module Iterator where
import Data.Functor.Product             -- Product of Functors
import Data.Functor.Compose             -- Composition of Functors
import Data.Functor.Const               -- Const Functor
import Data.Functor.Identity            -- Identity Functor (needed for coercion)
import Data.Monoid (Sum (..), getSum)   -- Sum Monoid for Integers
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy         -- State Monad
import Control.Applicative              -- WrappedMonad
import Data.Coerce (coerce)             -- Coercion magic

-- Functor Product
(<#>) :: (Functor m, Functor n) => (a -> m b) -> (a -> n b) -> (a -> Product m n b)
(f <#> g) y = Pair (f y) (g y) 

-- Functor composition
(<.>) :: (Functor m, Functor n) => (b -> n c) -> (a -> m b) -> (a -> (Compose m n) c)
f <.> g = Compose . fmap f . g

type Count = Const (Sum Integer)

count :: a -> Count b
count _ = Const 1

cciBody :: Char -> Count a
cciBody = count

cci :: String -> Count [a]
cci = traverse cciBody

lciBody :: Char -> Count a
lciBody c = Const $ test (c == '\n')

test :: Bool -> Sum Integer
test b = Sum $ if b then 1 else 0

lci :: String -> Count [a]
lci = traverse lciBody

clci :: String -> Product Count Count [a]
clci = traverse (cciBody <#> lciBody)

wciBody :: Char -> Compose (WrappedMonad (State Bool)) Count a
wciBody c =  coerce (updateState c) where
    updateState :: Char -> Bool -> (Sum Integer, Bool)
    updateState c w = let s = not(isSpace c) in (test (not w && s), s)
    isSpace :: Char -> Bool
    isSpace c = c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'

wci :: String -> Compose (WrappedMonad (State Bool)) Count [a]
wci = traverse wciBody

clwci :: String -> (Product (Product Count Count) (Compose (WrappedMonad (State Bool)) Count)) [a]
clwci = traverse (cciBody <#> lciBody <#> wciBody)

-- | the actual wordcount implementation. 
--   for any String a triple of linecount, wordcount, charactercount is returned
wc :: String -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
wc str = 
    let raw = clwci str
        cc  = coerce $ pfst (pfst raw)
        lc  = coerce $ psnd (pfst raw)
        wc  = coerce $ evalState (unwrapMonad (getCompose (psnd raw))) False
    in (lc,wc,cc)

pfst :: Product f g a -> f a
pfst (Pair fst _) = fst
psnd :: Product f g a -> g a
psnd (Pair _ snd) = snd

main = do
    putStrLn "computing three counters in one go"
    print $ wc "hello \n world"
```